# jquery each on <a> doesnt iterate on the element itself

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have HTML structure like this

```
<ul id="nav">
    <li><a href="http://localhost/.../">Homepage</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://localhost/.../">Our Profile</a></li>
    ...
    ...
    ...
</ul>
```

What I want to do with that HTML structure is to highlight an `<a>` element according to its `href` value. So I code a little jquery script like this

```
jQuery("ul#nav li a").each(function(index, element){
    if($(this).attr("href") == "http://mypreferredURL.com"){
        $(this).addClass("example");
    }
});
```

But that just doesn't work. I thought `$(this)` on that little jquery snippet should refer to the matched `<a>` element right? but it appear that `$(this)` is referring to the `href` value of the  element, instead the  element itself (I tested it by doing `alert($(this));`)

So, am I doing something wrong here? how can I really iterate through all those `<a>` element and really get `<a>` element itself instead of the `href` value of it.

Or if you have a better suggestion for me to do this kind of thing (highlighting the  element according to its href value), I'll be so glad to hear your suggestion :)

thx before

Comment: Pretty strange, this should be working, but what if you try `$(element)`

Comment: This is not the case; http://jsfiddle.net/CcCuk/

Comment: Are you sure that `$ == jQuery`? Are you using prototype.js as well?

Comment: @Niels: using $(element) is completely the same as $(this)

Comment: @Matt: hmm... I know it should works right?

Comment: @Eris: yes, I'm using prototype too, so I have to use that jQuery instead of $,,, is there something wrong with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> @Eric: yes, I'm using prototype too, so I have to use that jQuery instead of $,,, is there something wrong with it?

Yes. You're using the prototype `$` where you mean the jQuery `$`. To fix that, you should either use:

```
jQuery("ul#nav li a").each(function(index, element){
    if(jQuery(this).attr("href") == "http://mypreferredURL.com"){
        jQuery(this).addClass("example");
    }
});
```

or

```
(function($) {
    $("ul#nav li a").each(function(index, element){
        if($(this).attr("href") == "http://mypreferredURL.com"){
            $(this).addClass("example");
        }
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Your best choice would be *not to use both jQuery and prototype*!

Answer (score 3):

[I don't see a problem](http://jsfiddle.net/Eric/ELd4F/).

Note that there's no point using `jQuery` there, if you're going to use `$` anyway.

---

In terms of more concise ways to do it, you can use the [`[attr~="value"]` selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/):

```
$('ul#nav li a[href^="http://mypreferredURL.com"]').addClass("example");
```

This will find all links starting with `http://mypreferredURL.com`

Comment: I'm using prototype too (on Magento), that's why I use jQuery instead of $...

and actually I need those each function because I have to make a little editing on the href value before it gets compared with my prefered URL... you know, like concatenating the URL which use relative path with the domain name.. and stuff like that

do you have any other suggestion?
thanks :)

Comment: @MustafaKamal: See my other answer. Why would you concatenate relative paths? Are you just looking for onsite links?

Comment: actually I wanna highlight link to recent page...
anyway, your answer help me... I've just realized that I was getting with jquery's $ versus prototype $
thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing should work but this is a shorter way assuming you only want to check for one url?:

```
$('#nav li a[href="http://mypreferredURL.com"]').addClass("example");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/infernalbadger/ELd4F/1/

Answer (score -1):

you are wrong - everything is fine.

according to

http://jsbin.com/evaxaj/edit

it does five you the object 'a'

and 
http://jsbin.com/evaxaj/2/edit

gives you the SRC.